# Restricting Access for Collaborators on Github

Tags: github

I have a github repo which I want potential contractors to only **view/browse the codebase on Github** and **NOT download/clone the whole repository**. Is it possible to do it on Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [define an organization, and then teams](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-organization-account), because the permission level is richer with organization: see "[Permission levels for an organization repository](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization-repository)".

But unless the repo is private (and completely invisible), you cannot prevent a pull or a fork.

Comment: Organizations allow any user to "Fork (copy) the team's assigned repositories".

Comment: @RailsNewbie indeed. Even a pull is possible. So no, I didn't see a way to prevent cloning.